# GET request in php

Tags: php

Когда я посылаю в ссылке что то вроде href="topic.php?language=c++", на страницу topic.php наверзу видно topic.php?language=c++. То есть вроде бы всё работает, однако когда пытаюсь использовать $_GET он берет только букву с.Зачем и как это исправить?

```
  echo $_GET["language"];
```

result: c(без ++ и даже если передать с#, то он опять покажет с без #)

Answer (score 4):

В строке uri символ `+` равнозначен пробелу, т.е. вы фактически передаёте символ `с`, за которым следуют два пробела, и чтобы в этом убедиться, распечатайте $_GET таким способом: `var_dump($_GET);`.

Для преобразования пользуйтесь чем-то вроде `urlencode()` - с её помощью символ `+` будет преобразован в `%2B`, т.е., два "нормальных" плюса будут выглядеть так: `%2B%2B`, а строка uri примет следующий вид: `?language=c%2B%2B`, при этом `var_dump($_GET);` вам отобразит:

```
array (size=1)
  'language' => string 'c++' (length=3)
```